# Tag badges per user SEDE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange

I wanted to see where I lined up with other users on tag badges (I wanted to count just bronze but figured I would start with all of them to start out with).

Here is the query that I ended up with:

```
SELECT
    Users.Id as [User Link]
    , Users.DisplayName
    , COUNT (Badges.Id) AS Number_of_Tag_Badges
FROM 
    Badges
    INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagName = Badges.Name
    INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Badges.UserId
GROUP BY Users.DisplayName, Users.Id
ORDER BY Number_of_Tag_Badges DESC
```

What can be done to make this a better query?

Comment: I can't think of anything I would change!

Comment: SQL has a comma-first syntax convention?

Comment: @konijn it's not uncommon. It makes it easier to not add an extra comma at the end of the list. I also find it easier to add stuff to the end of the line without mucking about with the trailing comma.

Comment: Why do you select `Users.Id` as `[User Link]` *and* `DisplayName`?

Comment: @TimStone it is exactly that in the SEDE query, a link to the user's profile on the site

Comment: Right, so unless you need `DisplayName` separately you can avoid joining to `Users` altogether by just doing `Badges.UserId AS [User Link]`

Comment: You have to join on the users table because you need the display name for the spring on that column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Implementation

The query is quite well written for what it does.  I just have a few minor nitpicks about its implementation.

The `FROM`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` clauses are all subsidiary to the `SELECT` clause.  Therefore, I would indent them by one level.  (Indenting your `INNER JOIN` clauses so that they are part of the `FROM` clause was good.)

You're getting the disadvantages of the comma-first convention without reaping the benefits.  The advantage of putting commas first is that it makes it foolproof to add or remove columns in the `SELECT`: you should be able to delete an entire line of text without having to worry about fixing commas on neighbouring lines.  However, to take advantage of that property, you should put the first column on the same line as the `SELECT` keyword:

```
SELECT Users.Id as [User Link]
     , Users.DisplayName
     , COUNT (Badges.Id) AS Number_of_Tag_Badges
    FROM …
```

Remove the space before the parenthesis in the `COUNT (…)` call.

The joins would be better if the tables were listed linearly:

$$ \fbox{Users} \overset{\texttt{UserId}}{\longleftrightarrow}
   \fbox{Badges} \overset{\texttt{Name}}{\longleftrightarrow} \fbox{Tags}$$

Since the displayed results are user-centric, I would suggest listing the tables as `Users`, `Badges`, `Tags` rather than any other order.

### Concept

It would be handy if you added a rank column.

The query doesn't distinguish between gold, silver, and bronze badges.  You should be able to report the breakdown.  The [convention used by the International Olympic Committee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_medal_table) is to sort by the gold medal count first, rather than by the total.  Perhaps you should do the same.

```
WITH EarnedTagBadges AS (
    SELECT Users.DisplayName
         , Badges.UserId
         , Badges.Name
         , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Users.Id, Badges.Name ORDER BY Date) AS Level
        FROM Users
            INNER JOIN Badges ON Users.Id = Badges.UserId
            INNER JOIN Tags ON Badges.Name = Tags.TagName
), UserTagBadges AS (
    SELECT UserId
         , DisplayName
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Gold
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Silver
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Bronze
         , COUNT(Level) AS Total
        FROM EarnedTagBadges
    GROUP BY UserId, DisplayName
)
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Gold DESC, Silver DESC, Bronze DESC) AS Rank
     , UserId AS [User Link]
     , DisplayName
     , Gold
     , Silver
     , Bronze
     , Total
    FROM UserTagBadges
    ORDER BY Gold DESC, Silver DESC, Bronze DESC;
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't like anything unnecessary in code.
The "INNER" terms are unnecessary in this query.
Some might say that *[INNER JOIN can be a bit clearer to read, especially if the query has other join types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565640/641955)*,
but since in this question there's only one join type it's a moot point.
In short, I'd drop the "INNER".

Another unnecessary element is the `COUNT(Badges.Id)`,
which could be simply `COUNT(*)` so I don't wonder about the possibility of differences.

When I compared the two versions of the query with `COUNT(Badges.Id)` and `COUNT(*)` I got a different ordering. Since we order by count,
the ordering of lines with the same count is undefined.
I'd recommend to add one more column for ordering to get more consistent output, for example:

```
SELECT
    Users.Id as [User Link]
    , Users.DisplayName
    , COUNT (*) AS Number_of_Tag_Badges
FROM 
    Badges
    JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagName = Badges.Name
    JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Badges.UserId
GROUP BY Users.DisplayName, Users.Id
ORDER BY Number_of_Tag_Badges DESC, Users.DisplayName
```

All this is nitpicking though, nice query!

Comment: Hmm I guess I'd be one of those others.

Comment: [`COUNT(*)` vs. `COUNT(1)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221559/1157100)

Answer (score 4):

Minor note on consistency. You use a newline for your `SELECT` and `FROM`, but not your `ORDER BY`. Otherwise, it's pretty straight forward. I don't see anything smelly about it.

```
SELECT
    Users.Id as [User Link]
    , Users.DisplayName
    , COUNT (Badges.Id) AS Number_of_Tag_Badges
FROM 
    Badges
    INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagName = Badges.Name
    INNER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Badges.UserId
GROUP BY 
    Users.DisplayName, Users.Id
ORDER BY 
    Number_of_Tag_Badges DESC
```

Comment: the reason I don't do it for the Group By and the Order By is because they only had one term or were not complex enough to warrant spreading them out.  honestly the `GROUP BY User.Id` was an after thought when I added the user link column

Comment: And that's pretty fair @Malachi. Like I said, it was really nit picky.

Comment: it's good to keep me on my toes....lol I like to stay consistent so that when I read my code I remember what is going on accurately